# Two forms in the same action, each of them with a different submit button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework2

I have two forms on the same page, both having the same action in controller. In the first form I introduce some data, and after I save it in a table in database, using modal from jquery and remaining on the same phtml page, I use the id of it to enter it in a field in the table of the second form, because I need to introduce more lines on the same id of the first form. It's like for invoice no. 2 from table1, I want to have 2,3 or whatever lines in the second table. My problem is that when I press the submit button to save the second form data, it wants to save even the first form data, which is already saved and doesn't make the saving.

Do you have any idea how to do this without rewriting all the code with ajax?
Is there any way to put a condition for the second submit button?
I use zend framework 2 and jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give the second submit button a name that isn't found in the first form, and check for that input name in the post to the controller. If you find it, process form 2, if you don't process form 1.

Comment: I tried changing the name of the button, but when I do that my scripts don't work anymore and the web page transforms in a classic old view and the submit buttons don't have their functionality anymore.

Comment: Just by changing the name of a button? Sounds like you've got gremlins on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare validation (input filter) for each submit button (required => true) for using isValid() method forech forms

Form1 isValid when all input is correct and form 1 submit button is clicked
Form2 isValid when all input is correct and form 2 submit button is clicked

Comment: I tried putting input filter to buttons two, but that doesn't work. For the other fields I already had input filters.

Comment: It's ok, thanks guys, but I solved it. I put two if conditions in the action after I verified if it's posted instead of verifying validation of form2 in the condition where I verified if the first form is posted. I extracted the id of data inserted from form 1 and used it in the second form. Now my problem is I don't know how to insert more rows at once in table 2 when hiting save button. I read about INSERT IN table2 VALUES (x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2)..., but I need to insert more than one line without knowing the exact values I need to enter in database. Just the user knows how many rows he needs